# How to create rounded smaller spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want create a spinner with rounded corners and also it should not covers the whole width of the screen as of default spinner covers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an animation with an image like this :

```
ImageView spinner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_indefinitely));
```

with rotate_indefinitely anim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Comment: dear Damien Praca your code was perfect. but i was talking about the combo box(spinner called in android). you thought that i m talking about the object which spins.. :)

Comment: Oh yes sorry i though you were talking about the loading patience.

Comment: its Ok. now as u have understood my question then plz help

Comment: As far as I know, Spinner is like a Button, just create a selector and specify a drawable for each state. this link should help you : http://adanware.blogspot.fr/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html